# Cannot create zone in Google Cloud. How to solve this?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, googledns

I've been trying to create a zone file in Google Cloud but encountered the bellow error message.

> The DNS name (or its child domains) may be reserved or registered
>   already, prohibited by policy, or there may be no DNS name server
>   shards remaining for the name. For more information see
>   https://cloud.google.com/dns/quotas#nameserver_limits.

I used the domain before, but I shutdown the project.

Any solution please kindly help?

Comment: How long ago did you shutdown the project (resources are not automatically deleted immediately)? Do you have a balance due on the previous project (pay the balance and delete the resources in that project)? Do you own the domain (purchase another domain name)? Edit your question with details. We can only guess with the information provided.

Comment: 1) No. I don't have any due balance.

Comment: Can you check your quota ? Run "gcloud compute regions describe example-region" - it's described in the same documentation you linked to. Can you create zones for different domains ?

Answer (score 3):

Yup.  It appears that deleting projects does not remove the entry reservation.

Undelete the project(s), remove entries and then zone, re-delete project.

I am testing IaC so I probably have 30 deleted projects by now and have put together a script to do the above.  I have not been able to find an existing one.

Comment: Thank you for posting that, @george.Olson. That was exactly the problem I was facing. Thank you, thank you. :)